# Updating database with math formulas

Tags: php, mysql, select

I am trying to get my rating system going which will be the basis of my website.  How can I UPDATE the database with a +1 (to the number_of_ratings) column and add 1 to 5 (depending on the user input[what they rated]) to the ratings_value column.  These are then divided in php to come up with the average_rating, but I believe that is correctly done.  I'm new to prepared statements, and that's what I am trying to work with.  Thank You

```
<?php

include'config.php';

// Check Connection

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

$query = "SELECT brand, name, ratings_value, number_of_ratings, average_price, review, image, ratings_value FROM Products WHERE product_id = 0";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
printf ("%s<br />%s<br />%s<br />%s<br />%s<br />%s\n",
$row["brand"],
$row["name"],
$average_rating = $row["ratings_value"]/$row["number_of_ratings"],
$number_of_ratings = $row["number_of_ratings"],
$row["average_price"],
$row["review"],
$ratings_value = $row["ratings_value"]);

// using this will round value to nearest quarter - 0.25 - using 3 (nearest third), using 2 (nearest half), using 10 (nearest 10th)
//$average_rating = round(($average_rating*4), 0)/4;

$average_rating = round(($average_rating),2);

$background = round($average_rating/5*120);

if ($average_rating <= 5){ 
print ("<div style=\"width:{$background}px; background-color:#ffff00\"><img style=\"width:120px; height:30px\" src=\"stars.png\" /></div>");
}
else { 
print ("A value over 5? Not possible!<br />We are working to solve this as soon as we can");
}

?>
<form method="POST" action="womensjeggings.php">
<input type="radio" name="new_ratings_value" value="1" />1<img src="small_star.png">&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="new_ratings_value" value="2" />2<img src="small_star.png">&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="new_ratings_value" value="3" />3<img src="small_star.png">&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="new_ratings_value" value="4" />4<img src="small_star.png">&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="new_ratings_value" value="5" />5<img src="small_star.png">
<input type="hidden" name="new_number_of_ratings" value="1" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

// womensjeggings.php - most likely, far from correct

```
<?php
mysql_query("UPDATE Products SET ratings_value = '$ratings_value+$new_ratings_value', number_of_ratings = '$number_of_ratings+$new_number_of_ratings' WHERE product_id = 0");

?>

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=index.php">
```

Comment: the above code does this... http://thegreatest.zymichost.com/index.php ... however, the rating option isn't functional yet, everything else, in my opinion, looks good.  If you're curious, I manually entered the numbers in the database to test. the first number (line 3) is the ratings_value (17 in database) divided by number_of_ratings (5 in database) to get the average ratings (the number on line 3).  The second number (on line 4) is 5, that's the number of ratings... both numbers shown are what I want visible to the user.  The stars is shaded based on a percentage 3.4/5  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a separate table for this. The columns would be

```
user_id (int)
product_id (int)
rating (int)
```

Optionally, you could have an ID field as well, but it's not mandatory. Then to get a rating, you select the average of the votes using mysql's AVG() function based on the product ID. Remember to update a persons rating if they have voted on a product before

This of course assumes that your application has users with user ID's

Comment: a separate table?  I'm looking at having thousands of different items, how would that work?  I was working with someone previously, and they were basically telling me to update - which means, to change... the current value with a plus this number value, but that person isn't available and it was beginning to get confusing.

Comment: all I need to do... in case I wasn't clear... is add 1 to the number of ratings for every submission, which is where the input type="hidden" comes in and add 1 to 5 (based on user's rating) to an already existing ratings_value column.

Comment: You *could* do that, but the problem with doing that is that you haven't kept a record of **who** supplied a rating. That makes your system close to worthless, because what's to stop someone who really likes or really hates a product from repeatedly rating it up or down?

Comment: yes, I was thinking that too.  How can use a facebook connect instead of my own login/register system.  I've always wondered about the facebook connect.  And would that work for this purpose?

Comment: can I somehow record their IP address and require that to be unique (they can only vote on each product once)?  I was hoping to get a bigger response by not requiring a login.

Comment: Not sure about the facebook connect, but the biggest issue with your current system is that you don't track how many times someone votes, so like @Hammerite said, they can rate as much as they want. The point of the separate table is you can log each vote

Comment: I was going to try and record a user's ip address as a primary key along with the product_id being primary key as well.  Then, whenever the product_id AND the ip_address combined are the same value, a user can't vote a second time.  They would have to vote for another item.

Comment: I successfully recorded ip address in database as ip2long and required that field to be unique with each item.  As far as I know, it works.  :)